# R replace values in column based on match between columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframes, each with the same columns. Some columns have the same values in the same order in both dataframes (`X1`, `X2` below). Other columns have the same values, but in a different order (`Y1`). This is only a problem for some levels of first variables (here, the order of rows in Y1 differs for `X1 == "a"`, but not `X1 == "b"`). Example:

```
df1 <- data.frame("X1" = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b"),
                  "X2" = c("1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3"),
                  "Y1" = c("d", "d", "f", "g", "h", "i"))
df2 <- data.frame("X1" = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b"),
                  "X2" = c("1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3"),
                  "Y1" = c("f", "d", "d", "g", "h", "i"))
```

I would like to change the values of `df2$X1` and `df2$X2` such that the two dataframes are matched on values of `Y1`.

I would like to change `X1` and `X2` rather than `Y1` because there are many `Y` variables. I would like to do this only for `df$X1 == "a"`.

The output should looks like this:

```
df2 <- data.frame("X1" = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b"),
                  "X2" = c("3", "1", "2", "1", "2", "3"),
                  "Y1" = c("f", "d", "d", "g", "h", "i"))
```

Comment: Do you just want to arrange them differently?

Comment: Well, I want to arrange the X1, X2 columns differently so that they align with the Y1 column the same way they do in the other dataframe.

Comment: could you please provide your desired output as a data.frame

Comment: Done - apologies for the unclear description.

Comment: Your duplicate values make this more complicated (you have two values of `d` for `Y1` which correspond to different values of `X2`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is a little tricky in your situation is that you have duplicates in the `Y1` columns which correspond to different values in the `X2` columns. So you will have to make these unique.

First, make sure that your `Y1` columns are character vectors and not factors:

```
df1 <- data.frame("X1" = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b"),
                  "X2" = c("1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3"),
                  "Y1" = c("d", "d", "f", "g", "h", "i"),
                  stringsAsFactors = F)

df2 <- data.frame("X1" = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b"),
                  "X2" = c("1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "3"),
                  "Y1" = c("f", "d", "d", "g", "h", "i"),
                  stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Give unique names to your `Y1` duplicates:

```
df1$Y1uniq <- make.unique(df1$Y1)

df2$Y1uniq <- make.unique(df2$Y1)
```

Then you can use `match()` using those uniques values (and remove that column once you don't need it anymore):

```
df1[match(df2$Y1uniq, df1$Y1uniq), ][ , 1:3]
```

Output:

```
  X1 X2 Y1
3  a  3  f
1  a  1  d
2  a  2  d
4  b  1  g
5  b  2  h
6  b  3  i
```